# Post flagged as duplicate, but I still don't know the answer to my question!

Tags: discussion

[This post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/707136) was flagged as duplicate to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/148216/reality-of-length-contraction-in-sr), but I couldn't understand all the replies very well. Mr John Rennie's reply seems to agree with my initial thought process, but I could be wrong; **Is the answer to my question a Yes or a No?** Because I'm confused...

Can we interpret the length contraction of an object (or event) that someone observes in spacetime, as a result of his own (the observer's) rotation in spacetime? Just like we can observe a different part of an object's shape in space if we move around of that object?

Comment: If you don't think your question is a duplicate, please *edit* it and explain why

Comment: It is a duplicate, but the answers that the duplicate contain don't answer my question - therefore what am I supposed to do? How am I going to ask if you guys keep talking my question down? All I want is a yes or no answer.

Comment: I think it's clear from John Rennie's excellent answer to the duplicate what the correct answer is.  The answers specifically addresses the rotation issue.   The correct process if you still have confusion is to *explain that confusion* ideally by editing your original question.  There's a reopen queue where people with enough reputation can vote to reopen (or not) once you make an edit.  But you do need to make clear what about the answers to the duplicate you do not understand.  Asking for a "yes-no" is unlikely to get you anything more than the duplicate explains, IMO.

Comment: If it is clear then what is the answer? I have confusion because you guys keep taking down my question. If you STOPPED DOING THAT and ALLOWED people to answer me - I WOULDN'T HAVE CONFUSION. "clear what about the answers to the duplicate you do not understand" none of them - OBVIOUSLY... I asked something, is it correct? Yes or No? It can't be both... How TERRIBLE is that I have to talk to you about a question that WASN'T ALLOWED TO EVN BE POSTED?! Can't you get into my shoes and understand how that feels!? OBVIOUSLY there are things that I don't understand, SO LET ME ASK. Gatekeepers...

Comment: @Nuke John Rennie explicitly said "Lorentz contraction ... is not a contraction at all. Instead it is a rotation and ... its proper length, doesn't change at all". The way I understand your question, that is a super clear and direct answer. If you feel that does not unambiguously answer your question then you really need to edit it to explain why. Merely stating that you are confused isn't useful, we need to know **why** you are confused. What about his answer is not clear and what **specific** confusion remains? FYI, yes/no questions and answers are discouraged as they rarely help others

Comment: So the answer to my question is yes... At least that's what I understood from all of this.

Comment: with due respect: this site is not about answering *you*, and the suggestion that we should disregard duplicates because you do not understand the answers there is a guaranteed way to pollute the site with near-identical versions of the same questions.  Moreover, questions with yes/no answers do not fit well in the scope of the site, which is “to build a library of **detailed** answers to every question about physics, astronomy and astrophysics.”